# Probability of discrete random variable exceeding the expected value

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I am trying to the following:

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable that takes on a finite number of values.
Show that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \geq \mathbb{E}(X))>0
$$

I know that $\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i p_X(x_i)$ in this case, but I just dont know where go from there. I thought that mabye I should use contradiction and say $\mathbb{P}(X \geq \mathbb{E}(X)) = 0$ and then $\mathbb{P}(X<\mathbb{E}(X)) = 1$.

Comment: Yes you are right, now just need to finish the argument by contradiction.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I cant seem to find a proper contradiction. Have you mabye got a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if  $\mathbb{P}(x<\mu) = 1$

then $$\sum_{X < \mu }  P(x=X) =1$$

so $$\mathbb{E}(X)\equiv \mu= \sum_{X < \mu } X \cdot P(x=X)$$

$$ \implies \mu < \mu  \sum_{X < \mu }P(x=X) $$
$$ \implies \mu < \mu  $$